# Spring boot error 403 Forbidden only sometimes

Tags: spring-boot, http-status-code-403

On my local system the system works perfectly fine. But when the application is deployed to UAT, I get 403 error for all the APIs only sometimes. Sometimes the same API works fine. I'm not sure about this sometimes issue. Following is the configuration -

```
@Configuration
public class JWTSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Autowired
    MyJwtAuthenticationManagerResolver trustedIssuerJwtAuthenticationManagerResolver;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {

    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.antMatchers("/oed/api/**").authenticated()).oauth2ResourceServer(
                    oauth2ResourceServer -> oauth2ResourceServer.authenticationManagerResolver(
                            this.trustedIssuerJwtAuthenticationManagerResolver));

    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()
    {

    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "PUT"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the AWS API Gateway which we are using registered a route for my application which was also used by another application. We changed this configuration and the application works fine now. There was no code level issue, it was server configuration issue.